# Is 動物語 a valid term for the sounds that animals make?

Tags: word-choice, words, animals

Animals make sounds and communicate. Is there a proper name collectively for these sounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it could be '[動物]{どうぶつ}の[鳴]{な}き[声]{ごえ}'.
There are words for chirp and carol （さえずり）, barks （[吠]{ほ}えごえ）,etc. but as a collective term for the sound of animals, it is the only phrase I know of.

As for the '動物語', it is what we would likely come up with as a coined word for 'animal language', when we are anthropomorphizing animals playfully.

In fact, the first page of Google search results gives me a link to a toy called [動物語翻訳機]{どうぶつごほんやくき}, among others.